# My get method will not display arraylist value

Tags: java

I am new to java and stackOverflow so please be patient if I don't post all the necessary information about my question. Basically, I am trying to read  lines from a .txt file and store them in a Stack. I also need to access this Stack in a different class. So I created a get method but it always returns null. Please help!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Hints {

    private Stack stack;
    private File f;
    private String line;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public Hints(){          
        f = new File("hints.txt");
        stack = new Stack();    
    }

    public void getList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        scanner = new Scanner(f);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            stack.add(line); 
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public Stack getStack(){
        return stack;
    }

}
```

When I try to print the stack with a simple `System.out.print`, it will come out as `null`. Where is my issue(s)?
Thank you.

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your `print` code. stack should not be null.

Comment: Can you show the code that prints the stack?

Comment: Your code looks almost ok. So your issue must be with print method. Believe you defined it in another class and trying to create instance of Hint there which will print empty stack and not null.

Comment: When I call the getStack() method in another class is comes up empty. I can post another class where I use the method but I can only assume that the issue is coming from where I create the method and not where I am calling from. Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: @HenriqueAguiar Did you check my answer? Could it be that you accessed the stack without calling the getList() method before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. I think you are not calling the getList() method before you call the getStack() method.

```
try {
        Hints hints = new Hints();
        hints.getList();        // adds to the stack
        Stack s = hints.getStack();  // return the stack
        int stackSize = s.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < stackSize; i++) {

            System.out.println(s.pop());        // pop from the stack
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication18.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

You must call the getList() method first before you call the getStack() method. Because getList() method adds values that are read from the txt file. Then only you can call the getStack() method. Otherwise you don't have any values in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented looks fine so far. You initialize your stack by iterating through your textfile. So if the textfile contains lines, the stack will be filled with the data. So you might probably have a problem while printing your result.

Since `java.util.Stack` is derived from `Vector`, you can use the `get(int)` Method to access the data inside your stack. Therefore, you simply need a printing method that accesses the stack like this:

```
Hints h = new Hints();
h.getList();
Stack theStack = h.getStack();
for (int i = 0; i < theStack.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(theStack.get(i));
}
```

Now your stack should be printed correctly to the console.

And remember calling the `getList()` method before trying to access your stack. You should consider initializing the stack within the constructor. Maybe this is the thing you are missing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But where you getElement() come from? It does not seem to a method that is part he stack methods. Could it be get()?

Comment: @HenriqueAguiar Yes it is, I updated my answer. Didn't work with the java stack for a long time ;-). Here are the docs of the stack: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html. As you found out, it is "get()" and not "getElement()".

Answer (score 0):

This is my hint

```
 public Hints() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{          
    f = new File("hints.txt");
    stack = new Stack();   
    getList(); // call get list in constructor.
 }
```

When you create the hint its populate the stack.